# Standby password

Tags: password, gui, wakeup

My problem is that every five minutes my screen is getting dark and then asks me for a password.

How can I turn off the password request after computer's standby wakeup? Please show me where I can find the settings to disable the password.

Comment: @zloster While you are adding tags, why not improve the question a little more?

Comment: @MadMike Now should be better.

Answer (score 9):

#### For Ubuntu 11.04 and above:

---

You can access settings by typing `System Settings` in the Dash, or clicking "power" or "power cog" button in the top-right corner of the screen and choosing `System Settings`.

Once you entered on the `System Settings`, click on `Brigtness & Lock`.

[image: Brightness and lock]

#### For Ubuntu 10.10 and below or Ubuntu MATE:

---

You can access to the screensaver settings on `System` --> `Preferences` --> `Screensaver Settings` and then uncheck `Lock screen when screensaver is active`.

[image: Screensaver settings]

Comment: thank you but on my laptop is not like that,I have PLACES&SYSTEM and when I open that there is not SYSTEM SETTINGS,I do not know what to do to move standby password so if anybody have any suggestions I would be very happy man from Croatia!!!

Comment: What OS/version are you using?

Comment: I like screenshots =)

Comment: @MarkoHorvat this answer has 9 upvotes and you have never accepted. Why? =)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exactly answer the question, but it is another approach to the issue.

A couple of versions of Kubuntu ago, I couldn't figure out how to turn this off either.

Since I was kind of tired of screensavers anyway, I just turned the screen saving to start after an hour when power is plugged into my notebook (so it wouldn't come on while watching videos, etc.).

Then, I added an icon to my menu, and from there, to my panel that calls a script that just turns the screen off (which saves power and makes the screen and backlight last longer anyway). I just click on it when I want the screen off. It totally bypasses the system screensaver processing, so it only does what my script tells it to - no locking.

There's a delay in the script to give me time to get my hands away from the keyboard before it turns the screen off - because touching any key or the touchpad/mouse turns the screen back on - just like it does with a screensaver.

My original script had some old code in it. I cleaned it up before including it below.

```
#!/bin/bash
## Turn screen off - instead of screensaver
## Copyleft 03/22/2015 JPmicrosystems GPL

sleep 2s && xset dpms force off
```